# why does abs() function works for the position coordinate in Python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am looking at the Python document for turtle graphics, it has an example on drawing the turtle star. the program is as follow:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

I don't understand why the `abs(pos())` works? The `abs()` function takes a single argument, but the `pos()` function returns a position (x,y) coordinate. I know the program works, just don't understand why. I tried it on the Python interpreter with `abs((-0.00,0.00))`, it returns error. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

`pos()` returns a [turtle.Vec2D](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.Vec2D), not a tuple. You can make `abs()` work for any type by implementing `__abs__()`. In the case of turtle, `__abs__()` returns `(self[0]**2 + self[1]**2)**0.5` as per the turtle source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/turtle.py#L266).

Answer (score 2):

The `pos()` is not returning a tuple with x and y coordinate, instead it is returning an object of type `turtle.Vec2D`, this can be verified using:

```
>>> type(pos())
>>> turtle.Vec2D
```

Further if you run `dir(pos())` you may get:

```
['__abs__', '__add__', ... '__class__','count', 'index', 'rotate']
```

So the `turtle.Vec2D` object has its own `__abs__` implementation, but a generic `tuple` has no such implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `pos()` is NOT a 'normal' `tuple`. 
The turtle library defined a class called `Vec2D` (2 dimensional vector).
 `Vec2D` class does inherit from python's tuple but `abs()` functionality is overridden. 
Euclidean distance is calculated when `abs()` is called on a `Vec2D`.
Euclidean distance is the length measured from the point returned by `pos()` and the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use 'if t.heading() == 0:'. If my understanding isn't too incorrect, when 'turtle.heading == 0' then the turtle is facing 'east', the direction it started drawing from. This has worked for all the angles I've tried so far.

Using 'if abs(pos()) < 1:' ...  I can only draw images at the origin (0,0). (Maybe there's a way to draw images at other locations using 'if abs(pos()) < 1:' but I haven't figured out how.)

Using 'if t.heading() == 0:'
I can draw images anywhere on the screen.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Drawing Geometric Shapes")
wn.setup(980, 980)
Turbo = turtle.Turtle()
Turbo.color('red', 'yellow')
Turbo.speed(0)

#=====================================
def star(x, y, length, angle):
    Turbo.penup()
    Turbo.goto(x, y)
    Turbo.pendown()
    Turbo.begin_fill()
    while True:
        Turbo.forward(length)
        Turbo.left(angle)
        if Turbo.heading() == 0: #================
            break
    Turbo.end_fill()

#=====================================
#   (  x,    y,  length, angle)
star(-470,  300,  100,    120)
star( 360,  320,  100,    160)
star(-450, -340,  100,    100)
star( 360, -340,  100,    170)
star(-360,  0,    750,    178)

#=====================================
Turbo.penup()
Turbo.goto(-500, 0)
```